# Allocating class in the stack

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, allocation, stack-pointer

I was reading [this](https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2016/04/23/custom-memory-allocation-in-c-part-1/) article (which is about how to allocate class object in the stack segment) and came across to this snippet. If I understand correctly he wants to get the address of our `PocoClass` with the header (with lock object and type information).

```cs
TypedReference typedReference = __makeref(heapPoco);
int* poco1Address = (int*)(*(int*)(*(int*)(&typedReference)) - 4);
```

## Question

If we know that a class has 2 other "objects/information" before actual data, then why are we subtracting `4` (he's in **32bit** mode in his example) from our address, shouldn't it be `2 * 4`, because we have a pointer that points to "type object" and before that we have the "lock object".

Comment: No, second image in the blog post.  An object reference points to the 2nd field in the object header, not the object data.  Done to make accessing a boxed value as efficient as possible.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. Now it makes sense.